# list of list comparing

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I want to compare the amount of values in a list of a list.
If there would be an empty list in the one of the "sub" lists, it should print "too short".
If the list is long enough, meaning that it has more or 1 value in it, it should print "good". how can I do this?
No library imports please.

[image: listinlist_phyton]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please post code, not images of code. Please explain how this code's output differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the sub-lists and check for `len`, or just for falsey for empty lists as Python evaluates `[]` as `False`.

```
lists = [[1,2],[],[3,4,5]]
for l in lists:
    if len(l) < 1:  #or just `if not l:`
        print('too short')
    else:
        print('good')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate each element in the list and compare the length using the **len** function.

### Please see sample code below:

```
#list with one element sublist and 3 element sublist
a = [[1],[3,4,5]]
for index_length in a:
  if len(index_length) > 1:
    print("Good")
  else:
    print("too short")
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-python-list/#:~:text=Using%20Len()%20function%20to,elements%20present%20in%20the%20list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-a-python-list/#:%7E:text=Using%20Len()%20function%20to,elements%20present%20in%20the%20list).